# SQLiteException: No such table even if there is table

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, assets

*While trying to fetch the values from SQLite db this error came:-*

```
07-15 02:49:33.040: E/SQLiteLog(1770): (1) no such table: collegelist
07-15 02:49:33.040: D/AndroidRuntime(1770): Shutting down VM
07-15 02:49:33.050: W/dalvikvm(1770): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2acaba8)
07-15 02:49:33.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1770): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-15 02:49:33.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1770): Process: com.existingsqlitedatabase, PID: 1770
07-15 02:49:33.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1770): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.existingsqlitedatabase/com.existingsqlitedatabase.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: collegelist (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM collegelist
07-15 02:49:33.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-15 02:49:33.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-15 02:49:33.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-15 02:49:33.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-15 02:49:33.050: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
```

*I have checked the table(collegelist) in my database(colleges) and it is there but I don't know why it's not reading it. I have also checked here few earlier posts related to it but they didn't helped.*

**This is my DatabaseHelper class:-**

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{ 
private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window 
//destination path (location) of our database on device 
private static String DB_PATH = "";  
private static String DB_NAME ="colleges";// Database name 
private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;  
private final Context mContext; 

public DataBaseHelper(Context context)  
{ 
super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version 
DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/"; 
this.mContext = context; 
}    

public void createDataBase() throws IOException 
{ 
//If database not exists copy it from the assets 

boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase(); 
if(!mDataBaseExist) 
{ 
    this.getReadableDatabase(); 
    this.close(); 
    try  
    { 
        //Copy the database from assests 
        copyDataBase(); 
        Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created"); 
    }  
    catch (IOException mIOException)  
    { 
        throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase"); 
    } 
  } 
} 
//Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name 
private boolean checkDataBase() 
{ 
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME); 
    //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists()); 
    return dbFile.exists(); 
} 

//Copy the database from assets 
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException 
{ 
    InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME); 
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName); 
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024]; 
    int mLength; 
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0) 
    { 
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength); 
    } 
    mOutput.flush(); 
    mOutput.close(); 
    mInput.close(); 
} 

//Open the database, so we can query it 
public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException 
{ 
    String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME; 
    //Log.v("mPath", mPath); 
    mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY); 
    //mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS); 
    return mDataBase != null; 
} 

@Override 
public synchronized void close()  
{ 
    if(mDataBase != null) 
        mDataBase.close(); 
    super.close(); 
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

} 

 /**
 * Getting all labels
 * returns list of labels
 * */
public List<String> getAllLabels(){
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM collegelist";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning lables
    return labels;
   }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: ahhh.... in spite of helping u guys simply down vote the question.... looks like down voting gives some kind of achievement to you... at least put appropriate comment...

Comment: Have u pushed the db in DDMS/data/data/yourpacakage/databases folder?

Comment: no, but in assets folder

Comment: try to put there and try..

Comment: i mean i have kept it in assets :P

Comment: so what, try it in databases folder..

Comment: actually it automatically copies the db

Comment: Have you checked that the database file is really in /databases folder? Based on your code, the database file will be created if it fails to open it, resulting in empty database (no tables).

Comment: instead of copy from assets folder try to push in databases folder and remove copydatabase func.

Comment: For testing purpose, it might be a good idea to push the file directly to there. If the query works, then the real issue is database copying from /assets folder.

Comment: Yes there is some error in copying database from assets folder only...

Comment: but i am not able to find any error in it. How to fix the problem?

Comment: I see that `createDataBase()` is not called anywhere in the code. Try putting in inside `onCreate()` or the constructor, then uninstall and reinstall the app.

Comment: @Andrew T. Sir, I used the above codes from another project. When I use the database provided by them it works fine but as I switch it with my database it starts giving error

Comment: @Andrew T. Can you please explain me how to use `createDataBase()`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but try adding `db.createDataBase();` below `DataBaseHelper db = ...` inside `loadSpinnerData()`. Then check the LogCat for error log. You probably have to delete and reinstall the app again, or clear app data to test.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you more than this. I also don't know how to fix it.

Comment: No problem sir. I will find some other way. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: can you tried to call  `createDatabase()` in your `constructor`.You should call this method in your `DataBaseHelper` constructor.

Comment: @ved It is copying a blank database

Comment: I am posting my DatabaseHelper class which load database from my asset folder may be that helps you.

Comment: @ved According to Andrew T. if my code fails to open the database, no tables will be crated inside it. Which means my code fails to open the database but why so??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Load databaese from asset folder

```
public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public SQLiteDatabase database = null;
public File databaseFile;
public static String databaseName = "myDb";
public String databasePath = "";
Context mContext;

public DataHelper(Context paramContext) {

    super(paramContext, databaseName, null, 1);
    this.mContext = paramContext;


    this.databasePath = ("data/data/" + paramContext.getPackageName()+"/databases/"+databaseName);
    //this.databasePath = ("data/data/" + paramContext.getPackageName() + "/data.sqlite");
    this.databaseFile = new File(this.databasePath);
    if (!this.databaseFile.exists())
        try {
            deployDataBase(DataHelper.databaseName, this.databasePath);
            return;
        } catch (IOException localIOException) {
            localIOException.printStackTrace();
        }
}

private void deployDataBase(String dbNAme, String dbPath)
        throws IOException {
    InputStream localInputStream = this.mContext.getAssets().open(dbNAme);
    FileOutputStream localFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(dbPath);
    byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[1024];
    while (true) {
        int i = localInputStream.read(arrayOfByte);
        if (i <= 0) {
            localFileOutputStream.flush();
            localFileOutputStream.close();
            localInputStream.close();
            return;
        }
        localFileOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte, 0, i);
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (database != null)
        database.close();

    super.close();

}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: After using your class also an empty database was created in databases folder but outside the database folder one more file was created `data.sqlite` which was containing everything

Comment: I think this line is the reason for it `this.databasePath = ("data/data/" + paramContext.getPackageName() + "/data.sqlite");`

Comment: yes this line is the reason for this but this data.sqlite is your database file and you can perform your operation on this database file.

Comment: I change that line with ` this.databasePath = ("data/data/" + paramContext.getPackageName() + "/databases/"+databaseName);` and now its working perfectly but when I changed some data in my database and tested the code again, the change wasn't reflected can you tell me why? I mean the program checked if database file exists or not but when it found it exists it didn't checked for any update in data.

Comment: yes it checked for existing database file if found it doesn't updated.But if you want to update your database you set the database version and update it when new version is available in `onUpgrade()` and deploy every time your asset file in database.

Comment: Looks like I will have to do something in `onUpgrade()` but I found an alternative. I changed the database name in both assets folder & code, now it is showing the new data :) But its demerit is that it is consuming more space in phone as older database is still there. Any suggestions ved???

Comment: ` Log.w("TAG", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
  
     // Method to execute an SQL statement directly
     db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+DB_NAME);
     onCreate(db)`  **is this the proper coder to be written in `onUpgrade()` and what to write in `onCreate()`??**